# Overlaying a bitmap on the frame using Mediacodec and OpenGL-es

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, android-mediacodec

I have successfuly decoded a video and encoded again based on https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/DecodeEditEncodeTest.java
It uses a textureRenderer based on https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/TextureRender.java

Now I would like to change de `drawFrame` function to overlay a bitmap. I tried both using `GlUtils.TextSubImage2D` and `GlUtils.TextImage2D` and both returns GlError=1280. 
I am a newbie with OpenGl-es, and I'd really appreciate If someone could advice  me or tell me how to overlay the bitmap. I have seen this article: http://www.jayway.com/2010/12/30/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-vi-textures/
but I guess I have to use the already created texture together with `GlUtils.TextSubImage2D`.
Should I change the renderer to a framebuffer as it is in https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java which uses `GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D` instead of `GLES11Ext.Gl_Texture_External_Oes`?
 could someone help me please? thanks

```
    public void drawFrame(SurfaceTexture st)
    {
        checkGlError("onDrawFrame start");
        st.GetTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);
        GLES20.GlClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.GlClear(GLES20.GlDepthBufferBit | GLES20.GlColorBufferBit);

        // Select the program.
        GLES20.GlUseProgram(mProgram);
        checkGlError("glUseProgram");

        // Set the texture.
        GLES20.GlActiveTexture(GLES20.GlTexture0);
        GLES20.GlBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GlTextureExternalOes, mTextureID);

        mTriangleVertices.Position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
        GLES20.GlVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GlFloat, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
        checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
        GLES20.GlEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
        checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");
        mTriangleVertices.Position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
        GLES20.GlVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GlFloat, false,
            TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
        checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");

        // Enable the "aPosition" vertex attribute.
        GLES20.GlEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
        checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");

        Android.Opengl.Matrix.SetIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
        // Copy the model / view / projection matrix over.
        GLES20.GlUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.GlUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);

        // Draw the rect.
        GLES20.GlDrawArrays(GLES20.GlTriangleStrip, 0, 4);
        checkGlError("glDrawArrays");

        GLUtils.TexSubImage2D(GLES11Ext.GlTextureExternalOes, 0, 0, 0, bitmap, GLES20.GlRgb, GLES20.GlUnsignedByte);
        //GLUtils.TexImage2D(GLES11Ext.GlTextureExternalOes, 0, bitmap, 0);
        checkGlError("TexSubImage2D"); 


        GLES20.GlFinish();
    }
```

Comment: `glTexImage2D()` (note "tex", not "text") converts a pile of pixel data into a GLES texture. You can see an example of its use in Grafika's `GlUtil#createImageTexture()` method (https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/gles/GlUtil.java#L127). You can also find various other classes that are handy for drawing simple textured meshes (see the demos with bouncing squares and spinning triangles).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ? I have the exact same issue...

Comment: not yet. I am working on another project. But I met with an object detection sample of vuforia (https://developer.vuforia.com) where there is an example of doing this with opengles. It uses some vuforia calls, but I think it could be a kick off to see the way to solve it. If I return to this project and solve it I'll let you know. thanks